# jQuery animation on Phonegap stops working

Tags: jquery, ios, animation, cordova

I have an animation in my phonegap application on iOS that stops working completely sometimes. I have an element, which listens touchstart event on it. The handler should open a div, which initially has *display:none* set. I've tried the following functions to open the div with animation:

```
$("#sections").toggle();
$("#sections").slideToggle();
$("#sections").stop().slideToggle();
```

Apparently, it doesn't matter which function to use, the animation stops working. That is, it opens and closes the div several times first, but stops working after some arbitrary time. After failure, I can still see a debug message in the console on each *touchstart* event, but the animation just doesn't work anymore.

I'm using jQuery 1.8.1 and Phonegap 2.1.

Has anyone experienced anything like this?

The HTML code. The *touchstart* handler is bound to #navibtn (works fine) and the handler should open the #sections with animation:

```
<div id="navibar">
<div id="titlebar" class="row">
    <div id="navibtn" class="pull-right"></div>

    <div>
    <span>Title</span>
    </div>
    <div id="sections">
        <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active" id="link1">
            <a href="#section1">Section</a>
        </li>
        <li id="link2">
            <a href="#section2">Section2</a>
        </li>
        <li id="link3">
            <a href="#section3">Section3</a>
        </li>
        <li id="link4">
            <a href="#section4">Section4</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle jsfiddle.net for clarity